# Why can’t I see the second hop in tracert?

Tags: networking, traceroute

[image: Tracert from command line in Windows 10, newest patch - IPs removed]

`giga.cube` is my local router. My PC is connected to it via WiFi. After that I see a hop whose IP adress can't be seen nor pinged. Is this nominal?

Be aware that the GigaCube is connected to internet using a SIM card. It connects to mobile network (cell towers). Is that why I can't see the second ping? Or is there someone in between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is quite common and completely normal. I have often seen this. In Windows tracert is typically implemented by sending a series of ping requests. It is not required that a server or router respond to a ping request. It is not an essential service and the same technology used in ping can also be used for malicious purposes. For these reasons many administrators will choose to explicitly block these requests. A router can also assign different priorities to different kinds of network activity. Being a non essential service ping may be assigned a lower priority and when busy the router may not be able to respond in the allowed time or it may simply choose to not reply at all.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with a SIM card and everything to do with how routing is configured.  There are multiple scenarios which can cause this, 2 of which are -

- The router is not accepting ping requests.
- The router shares (an RFC1918)  IP as a device on your LAN.